# ImportError python WINFUNCTYPE

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I'm trying to run some code from here:http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577654-dde-client/

On my Windows machine, using Python 2.7.8 via x86_64 Cygwin

I keep getting:

```
 ImportError: cannot import name WINFUNCTYPE
 >>> from ctypes import WINFUNCTYPE
```

It appears that I am missing a standard library from somewhere with this and probably other functions... But I cannot figure out how to get this library or from where? I do not have a lot of experience with python, especially not with importing native libraries... Is there like a cpan perl install module type mechanism or... How can I update this to get my code to work?

Comment: Could it be, that Cygwin is the culprit here? Did you try it with the native system (i.e., Windows) Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you started *Cygwin*'s *Python* (by simply typing *python* in the *Cygwin* console) and not the one you want (*Cygwin* comes with *Python* in */usr/bin*). You can test that by typing in the *Python* console:

```py
import sys
sys.platform
```

It will output ***cygwin*** instead of ***win32***. To launch the correct *Python*, you must specify the full path *cygwinified* (meaning that if your python is installed under "*C:\dir1\Dir 2\python.exe*", you'll have to type **/cygdrive/c/dir1/Dir\ 2/python.exe**).